# Generating data with a given probability in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create data frame in **R** with Id and and gender of 50 employees. For that I used this code with `gl()` function.

```
gender<-gl(2, 25, label=c("Male", "Female"))
id<-1:50
df <- data.frame(id, gender)
```

But the problem here is the first 25 rows are "male" and the next 25 rows are "female". I want to generate gender  randomly with a 50% chance for each gender. Is there anyway to do it in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `sample()`

```
gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size=50, replace=TRUE)
```

You can also do things like create a vector in random order with exactly 25 males and females

```
sample(rep(c("Male","Female"),each=25)
```

or get proportions other than 50/50

```
sample(c("Male", "Female"), size=50, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.75,0.25))
```

Comment: +1, and of course it could be done in one step without creating the objects `id` and `gender` before creating the data.frame (e.g. `df <- data.frame(id = 1:50, gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 50, replace = T, prob = c(0.5, 0.5)))`)